# MS SQL Server 2016 insert reoccurring dates since last date with cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, cursor

I have an Invoice table for customers that are due to be invoiced each month. Same product/price every month. I've got the most recent rows for each customer (the last time they were invoiced) and I'm going through the data with a cursor. I need to check when the last invoice month was and if a new invoice is due, add a new row with the next month date. If the last invoice date was 2 months ago, then I need to add 2 entries, for example if the last date was October 4, I'll need to add a row for November 4 and December 4. I don't want to add any details that aren't due yet.

```
OPEN @getid
FETCH NEXT
FROM 
    @getid INTO @invoiceDate, @clientAccountID, @clientID, @CompanyName, @CompanyRole, @Charge, @receivedDDForm
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     INSERT INTO Invoices
     (invoiceDate, clientAccountID, clientID, CompanyName, CompanyRole, Charge, receivedDDForm, paymentReceived)
     SELECT 
     DATEADD(MONTH, 1, Convert(date, @invoiceDate)), @clientAccountID, @clientID, @CompanyName, @CompanyRole, @Charge, @receivedDDForm, 0

     --This is where I need help--      
     WHERE
     GETDATE() > @invoiceDate 
     OR
     DATEADD(MONTH, 1, Convert(date, @invoiceDate)) <= GETDATE()        

    FETCH NEXT

    FROM @getid INTO @invoiceDate, @clientAccountID, @clientID, @CompanyName, @CompanyRole, @Charge, @receivedDDForm
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Comment: SQL-2016 is the ISO/ANSI 9075-1 SQL standard. (https://www.iso.org/standard/63555.html)

Comment: Isn't GETDATE() > @invoiceDate always going to be true?

Comment: You're right, but for some reason it was adding a duplicate row with the last invoice date, so I had to put that there to stop it.

Comment: Fixed! Added the additional month to the date before it went into the cursor, then added If InvoiceDate Not Exists in the Insert statement. Puts in the next date only